# Using a built in sqlite3 database from a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I'm currently building a gem that uses a sqlite3 database to store parsed content from a website. When I run the gem name in the command line, while I'm inside of it's original file directory, the program runs without any problems.

However, when I install the gem to another project and try to run it I get an error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mtg-card-finder-0.1.1/config/environment.rb:8:in `initialize': unable to open database file (SQLite3::CantOpenException)
```

I have created the database file outside of the `lib` folder but it is referenced in my `environment` file:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'sqlite3'
require "tco"
require "mechanize"
require "nokogiri"
require "require_all"

DB = {:conn => SQLite3::Database.new("db/cards.db")} #this gives me validation to reach the database that module Persistable interacts with

require_all 'lib/mtg_card_finder' #this allows me to simultaneously require everything in lib/mtg_card_finder
```

Which is then required by my main file inside `lib`:

```
require_relative '../config/environment'

module MTGCardFinder
end
```

This is my first time building a ruby gem, so I know that I must be messing something up on my gemspec, or some other thing that I don't know of that isn't allowing the database to be accessible when installed as just a gem.

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'mtg_card_finder/version.rb'

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject do |f|
    f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  end

  spec.executables   << "mtg-card-finder"
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.14"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 12.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "pry", "~> 0.10.4"
  spec.add_dependency "rubysl-open-uri", "~> 2.0"
  spec.add_dependency "nokogiri", "~> 1.7.1"
  spec.add_dependency "tco", "~> 0.1.8"
  spec.add_dependency "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.13"
  spec.add_dependency "mechanize", "~> 2.7.5"
  spec.add_dependency "require_all", "~> 1.4"
```

Any advice would be so welcoming! :)
Here is the repo if you need additional lines from the gemspec and such:
https://github.com/JuanGongora/mtg-card-finder

Comment: if db/cards.db needs to be available in the app that uses it, i think it isn't because the "files" instruction in the gemspec filters out anything that is not a test, spec, or feature.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was, first I had to do a simple rearrange in my main `lib` file:

```
module MTGCardFinder #needs to be defined first so that environment loads correctly
end

require_relative '../config/environment'
```

Before my environment was requiring particular files that were children of the module `MTGCardFinder` so it was responding with an uninitialized constant error,  so I just had to define the module first so that the interpreter could read that before seeing what else was required.

Second fix was automatically making a directory that would contain the stored database, inside of the current directory where the gem would be installed. I had the original database folders within the gem but it wasn't accessing them, so this was the workaround:

```
require 'fileutils' # for creating the directory

DIR = "db"
FileUtils.makedirs(DIR)

DB = {:conn => SQLite3::Database.new("db/cards.db")} #this gives me validation to reach the database that module Persistable interacts with
```